# Why won't my NSLayoutConstraints squish my uiviews?

Tags: ios, nslayoutconstraint

I have the following views and layout constraints inside another view.

```
|-10-|[UIVIEW]|-10-|[UIVIEW]|-10-|[UIBUTTON]|---------- >= 523 ---------------|
```

All the UIVIEW's above are set to be (<= 125). And the UIButton is (= 150).

Why won't the UIVIEWS squish down? I would think the >= 523 would force the uiviews to shrink down?

What I what I am seeing is the following.

```
|-10-|[UIV  ]|-10-|[UIV   ]|-10-|[UIBUTTON]|----------------------------------|
```

What I want to see is.

```
|-10-|[UIV]|-10-|[UIV]|-10-|[UIBUTTON]|---------------------------------------|
```

UPDATE:

This is all built in Storyboard (i.e. not code)

The UIVIEW's are of type MyCustomView and they live in the main view of my storyboard. As a test, I colored the background of the MYCustomView.xib to be Blue. I set the UIVIEW's background to be red. When the following is show, I see that the blue background is hugging the "UIV" part of the [UIV   ], which is what it should be doing, but the extra space in the [UIV    ] is red. The following constraints are in the storyboard (i.e. the ones at the top of this post).

```
|-10-|[UIVIEW]|-10-|[UIVIEW]|-10-|[UIBUTTON]|---------- >= 523 ---------------|
```

Comment: What do you mean by "squish down"? What do you see with this code, and what do you want to see?

Comment: Check the edit above.

Comment: What constraints do you have for your UIViews? If they don't use auto layout, do you override intrinsicContentSize? Are you doing all of your constraints in code or are you building this layout in IB?

Comment: Have you done anything with the content hugging and compression properties?

Comment: You show blank space (e.g. `[UIV  ]`) suggesting that the view is wider than… something. How would the layout system know what that something is and how wide it is? Constraints saying that the views should be <= 125 points wide and the distance from the right button to the superview is >= 523 are ambiguous. There are an infinite number of layouts which satisfy them, assuming the width of the superview has any slack at all (i.e. it's >= 10 + 10 + 10 + 150 + 523).

Comment: That coupled with intrinsic content size and edge insets and the same of subviews will limit shrinkage and expansion.

Comment: @jdog we still need some more information about how those UIView's are constructed to determine why auto layout isn't compressing them. Are they actually just basic UIView's as containers? Are they subclasses? Do they use auto-layout? Did you override intrinsicContentSize for them?

Comment: @KenThomases I am not sure what you are saying?

Comment: @uchuugaka I haven't done anything with the content hugging or compression properties.

Comment: First point: By saying you want `[UIV]` but you're seeing `[UIV  ]`, you suggest that there's some "correct" width but the view is wider than that. What is that correct width? Where does it come from? How could the layout system know about it? Second point: inequality constraints are satisfied by an infinite number of possible layouts. If you don't provide the layout system enough information to pick one of those solutions over another, then the layout is ambiguous. There are many possible solutions and the system will pick one at random.

Comment: @KenThomases ok and how do I go about doing that?

Comment: To start with, answer the questions. What do you think is the right layout? Why? What makes it right and others wrong? How can that be expressed in ways Cocoa can understand (either additional constraints or an intrinsic size for the view)?

Comment: Can we cut with the philosophy here? Your questions are answered in the original question. The right is push, squish, hug everthing to the left. What is wrong is that the [UIVIEW    ] should not have any unused space. I don't want the [UIView    ] to push its inner content out to fill it, but rather I want the [UIView    ] to squish down if it doesn't have enough content to fill the space.

Comment: I just dictched the XIB and used components and it works perfectly.